# Electric Field in- and outside a conductor - calculation and concept

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, conductors

So I'm currently self-studying ED by Griffith, as I just finished the first chapter I decided to come back and do the problems.

`Problem 2.7 Find the electric field a distance $z$ from the center of a spherical surface of radius R that carries a uniform surface charge $\sigma$`

`Problem 2.8 Use your result in Prob 2.7 to find the field inside and outside a solid sphere of radius R that carries a uniform volume charge density $\rho$`

In the solutions for 2.7 for $z<R$ things cancel out nicely and we get $E_z=0$

For problem 2.8 however, the solution for $z<R$ we get a solution $\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\frac{Q}{R^3}$

The maths checks out, then later in that chapter he talked about how the electrons reside on the surface of a conductor, and inside the conductor, the electric field is 0.

So my question is, what is happening, why when we integrate over a volume element we get a solution for inside the sphere, and when we integrate over an area element we get 0?

***EDIT: I believe i was confused about the wording, the first one is a hollow sphere the second is a solid sphere. Thou the question remains, if the inside of a conductor isn't supposed to have an electric field inside, why do we get a result***?